# Read csv rows as arrays - python

Tags: python, arrays, list, csv

I have csv file with 4 columns and would like to create a python list of arrays,  with each csv row being an array.

I am able to get each row as an array but the problem is that the array begins and ends with quotes.

cvs data format:

```
User Link,Reputation,DisplayName,Location   
353410,"47245","John Doe","Uruguay" 
927034,"46782","Jane Doe","Bahia Blanca, Argentina"
```

This is one of the codes I tried:

```
with open('Query_SO_Arg.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    so_data = []
    so.next()
    for row in so:
        so_data.append(row)
    print so_data
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
[['353410,"47245","John Doe","Uruguay";'], ['927034,"46782","Jane Doe","Bahia Blanca, Argentina";'], ['62024,"41775","Jim Doe","Buenos Aires, Argentina";'],
```

How can I build this structure but without the external '' so I can work with the data?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is the data of a brand new csv file (with the same structure as the original one):

```
User Link,Reputation,DisplayName,Location
60000,"40000","Diego K","Buenos Aires, Argentina"
240000,"37000","Claudio R","Buenos Aires, Argentina"
```

This is the output I am getting (with the same old quote problem):

```
[['60000,"40000","Diego K", "Buenos Aires, Argentina"'], ['240000,"37000","Claudio R","Buenos Aires, Argentina"']]
```

EDIT 2
if I use the following code:

```
so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
for row in so:
    print ', '.join(row)
```

I get:

```
User Link, Reputation, DisplayName, Location
60000,"40000","Diego K","Buenos Aires, Argentina"
240000,"37000","Claudio R","Buenos Aires, Argentina"
```

The data seems to be ok with the exception that there are no lists. Does this give any clue of why I cannot make the move to building lists properly?

EDIT 3:
Per @MartijinPieters kind request I am posting the following code:

```
print repr(open('So_fake_data_test.csv', 'rb').read())
```

which outputs:

```
'User Link,Reputation,DisplayName,Location\r\n"60000,""40000"",""Diego K"",""Buenos Aires, Argentina"""\r\n"240000,""37000"",""Claudio R"",""Buenos Aires, Argentina"""\r\n'
```

Thanks @MartijinPieters

EDIT 4

[image: CSV screeshot]

I hope this helps. 
Thanks again.

Comment: That code shouldn't give you that output from that input.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. I do note that your output includes *semicolons*, which your input doesn't have.

Comment: All you need to do is use `list(csv.reader(csvfile))` to get your list of lists; the default dialect configuration *is enough*.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I have the above mentioned csc file and applied the above mentioned code...is there anything that I could be missing?

Comment: @Diego: your input says John Doe is in Uruguay, but the output says Argentina.  Your input doesn't have any semicolons, your output does.  You may *think* that's the file you're running that code on, but I assure you you're not.

Comment: @MartijinPieters thank you for the answer. The code outputs the same structure with the same quotes...which is the problem I am not being able to resolve.

Comment: @DMS thanks for the comment, I only edited some names for confidentiality matters (it is a typo). The input and output structures are the original ones (with the semicolons appearing in the output but not in the input).

Comment: @Diego the problem is that once you've made one typo, everything else that looks like it might be a typo is now useless for us to diagnose with. If you can't copy your current data due to confidentiality issues, then create NEW data, run it through your code, and give us the output.

Comment: @DMS I doublechecked and I am using the correct file. What do you think might be going on, I am clueless?

Comment: @DMS I understand the "credibility" issue but beyond changing the names when editing the question there is no other change made (ie, commas, semi-colons, etc). I just copied and pasted the rows from the input and the output.

Comment: @DMS I created a complete new file from scratch. When I tested I got the same kind of problem. Something I noticed is that when I created the file (in Excel) and save it to csv I got an alert message warning me that some properties of the file might not be compatible with a cvs file. Could this be related to my issue? Thanks

Comment: @Diego: how are you then copying the data from the file to your question? Because when I copy across and try to reproduce the problem, *it all just works*.

Comment: @Diego: see https://gist.github.com/mjpieters/bc4a573c4be1c79f1055

Comment: @Diego: I notice that your updated sample includes a space in front of a `"` quote (second line); that's not something Excel would produce. I had to add `skipinitialspace=True` to properly parse that column, but that space tells me your data was probably *not* a copy and paste.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, thank you for noticing the space. It is simply a typo since I created the data from scratch for enriching the question. The original data was copy/paste (besides names and country). It is edited now.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, thank you for the test...I see that it works for you in Gist. I deleted the space and still does not work for me (the lists are within quotes). What do you think the problem might be?

Comment: @MartijinPieters, another difference between your output and mine is that the first value of the second row (onwards) is between quotes in your case but not in mine (as in the new input data).

Comment: By using `str.join()` you are only obscuring the problem. Can you post the output of `print repr(open('Query_SO_Arg.csv', 'rb').read())` in your question please? That'll give us a far better idea of what file data you have.

Comment: Needless to say, it should be with a file that actually produces problematic lists for you.

Comment: Your output shows that you have one column on each row, containing data with commas. The CSV module is producing *exactly what you have in the columns*. Did you type those commas into one Excel cell?

Comment: To be clear, you can see from your file you have data with `"...."` on each line. Within those quotes the commas are **not** delimiters but parts of the  value. Contained `"` characters are doubled up, to escape them. So within the `"..."` on one line you have the **value** `60000,"40000","Diego K","Buenos Aires, Argentina"`.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, thank you for the time for the diagnostics. I did not type anything into the document. For some reason it is formatted like this. Is there anything I could do to get the data as I need it? What do you suggest? Thank you for the patience.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, the commas within double quotes are not visible in the csv file. For some reason they appear when reading the file...Does this make sense?

Comment: So what does the Excel file look like? Perhaps a screenshot of those cells is in order. How do you create the CSV file? And to be clear: this is a problem with how the file is being generated, not how Python reads the file. Python is correctly reading the data as one column because that's exactly how the CSV has been formatted.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, thanks for the follow up. I pasted the screen shot. I agree with your vision of the problem. FYI, I use Win 7.

Comment: @MartijinPieters, I tested the same data (created from scratch) and code with a Mac and the results were the same. It is not a Win related issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

The misterious problem is not related to the code or the data itself but to the way Excel saves the original downloaded data.

This is what I was doing: downloaded the csv file with the original data, opened it in Excel and saved it as a recognizable name.

This is the **solution** I found: download the csv file, go to Windows Explorer and rename the file.

With this basic operation and the following code everything works fine:

```
so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
so = list(so)
```

Thanks for all your inputs, specially to @MartijnPieters!

Answer (score 1):

this works for me (`Python 3.4`):

```
import csv
with open('Query_SO_Arg.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    so = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    so_data = []
    for row in so:
        so_data.append(row)

    print(so_data[1:])
```

The output is:

```
[['353410', '47245', 'John Doe', 'Uruguay '], ['927034', '46782', 'Jane Doe', 'Bahia Blanca, Argentina ']]
```

Comment: Thanks @dm295. I get the same output (with the quotes). I am using python 2.7, although I do not think is the issue here.

Comment: @diego - our outputs are not the same - you have a lists with only one item in them, my output lists have 4 items

Comment: Thanks, what I meant is that when I run your code I am getting a different output than what you are getting. I still get my unsatisfactory output (with the quotes). This is the issue that is happening with every solution proposed so far. I am not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in Python 3.11.1

```
import numpy as np
    
# row = f.getline()   
row = "1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4,5.5\n"
row_arr = np.asarray([float(i) for i in row.replace('\n','').split(',')])
print(row_arr)
```